# Converting pptx file to pdf using powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, automation, powerpoint

I am trying to convert .pptx file to .pdf using powershell. I have used below code

```
 write-host "Converting pptx to pdf....." -ForegroundColor Green
            $ppt = New-Object -com powerpoint.application
            $opt = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsPDF

            $ifile = $file.FullName
            $pres = $ppt.Presentations.Open($ifile)
            $pathname = split-path $ifile $filename = Split-Path $ifile -Leaf
            $file = $filename.split(".")[0]
            $ofile = $pathname + "\" + $file + ".pdf"
            $pres.SaveAs($ofile, $opt)
```

While running the code, i am getting error as:

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$pptx = "C:\test\test.pptx"
$pdf = "C:\test\test.pdf"
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$ppt.Visible = $True
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open($pptx)
$presentation.SaveAs($pdf, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsPDF)
$presentation.Close()
$ppt.Quit()
```

Comment: It is not readily obvious what your code does differently from the code in the question (other than calling `.Close()` and `.Quit()`). If there is a meaningful difference that resolves the problem, please update your answer to point it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).